# Problems installing Ruby 1.9.3 with Rvm

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, homebrew, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.3 using this guide: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/.

When I run `rvm install 1.9.3` I get this error

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary         rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.
```

Then I run `brew update`, I get

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Also I tried running `brew doctor`, and I get

```
Your system is raring to brew.
```

What is wrong? How do I fix this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

Source:

https://rvm.io/

Comment: This worked. I was using latest before via rvm get latest. I guess running that command on its own can lead to conflicts down the road. The above solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rvm list known
```

If that returns nothing, or doesn't include the ruby version you're looking for try to update

```
rvm get stable
```

Then try to install the ruby version you want again.