# error when run rvm requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I followed
[this tutorial](http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/05/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)
to install rvm on ubuntu 12.04
when run `rvm requirements`, I got the following message

```
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Running 'apt-get --quiet --yes update' would require sudo.
Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.
Updating repositories
Missing required packages: libgdbm-dev, libffi-dev.
Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.
```

I got same message when run `rvm install 1.9.3`

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes the official documentation it's more reliable than a blog. Take a look at the [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) documentation. The command from the blog to install rvm is:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

and the official documentation recommend that one:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --rails
```

Probably this will solve your problems with autolibs, the same that was happening for example in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643205/problems-installing-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm) .

Answer (score 8):

from https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs - there are two modes that will be useful for you:

1. `rvm autolibs read-only` - it will do all the steps and only show the required commands / missing libraries
2. `rvm autolibs enable` - it will install everything for you, it might require sudo password so a nice trick for tools like capistranos is to:

   ```
   rvm autolibs read-only
   sudo rvm --autolibs=enabled requirements ruby-2.0.0
   rvm install ruby-2.0.0
   ```

A writeup about autolibs https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/rvm-ruby-2-0

Answer (score 7):

I was getting some sort of same error:

`Missing required packages: libreadline6, libreadline6-dev, libyaml-dev, libffi-dev.
Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.`

Even though Ubuntu Software Center showing "libreadline6, libreadline6-dev etc" installed.

I got this fixed disabling autolibs:

`rvm autolibs disable`

ruby install 1.9.X worked!

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is to solve the rvm requirment error returns 100

If any deb command is commented in `/etc/apt/sources.list` than try to uncomment that command from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Command is:

```
$sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If problem is not solved than replace `sources.list` file with other Ubuntu's `sources.list`

Command is:

```
$mv <file path of sources.list from other Ubuntu machine> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**Please make a backup before doing that**

Command is:

```
$cp /etc/apt/sources.list sources_backup.list
```

*Problem should solve by this time, if not than reinstall the Ubuntu.*

Note: If sources.list file is corrupted than it will gives problem to install other packages.